# comboboxitem to be replaced by textbox on clicking

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am implementing a comboBox consisting of normal comboBoxItems and those which will allow the modification of the list bound to the comboBox.

Eg: I need the following to go into the comboBox - option1, option2, option3, AddNewOption
where, **upon clicking on the AddNewOption, I want the comboBoxItem to expose a textBox where I enter the content**, which will be dynamically added to the list bound to the comboBox.

How do I implement the highlighted portion?

Comment: may be I am missing your question but did you check with IsEditable="True", it may allow you to edit and have new value in combobox

Answer (score 0):

I would probably bind to an editable collection view that adds the [`NewItemPlaceholder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.newitemplaceholder.aspx) at the end, then one could define a `DataTemplate` for the place-holder which contains the outlined logic.